# Anonymous function error with d3.csv

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to load use a csv file to make a dataviz in d3js. I load the data with a very simple script :

```
<script>
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) { console.log(data);});
</script>
```

But when I look in my console, I've got an error message :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Does anyone has a solution ?

Here is a gist with the program and the data : https://gist.github.com/pachevalier/5821110

The error is not due to circularheatChart.js.

Comment: What else is on your page? Did you load d3 [ <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script> ] ?

Comment: Did you get a file/line no? What's in `js/circularHeatChart.js`? It'd be much easier to help if you included the whole source, and ideally put the problematic code on jsFiddle.

Comment: Often `$` is a signal that you need jQuery (since jQuery is the most common library that uses `$` as a global, reffered to as "bling"). You should try including jQuery with `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.js"> </script>` and see if that works. As @RichardMarr said though, you should give the code to  `circularHeatChart.js` to get help if adding jQuery doesn't fix it.

Comment: @elsherbini: yes, I did the same once, it worked. Can't remember what exactly caused it though

Comment: I've got the same problem with and without circularHeatChart.js and adding jquery doesn't solve the issue. Thanks for your comments.